# issue with ion-Slides

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to make ion-slides that show images but I can only show one image and the other images are in the left side and when I try to see it I can only see half ofor if I press the button I get white space 
[image]

[image]

```
 <ion-slides pager="true">
    <ion-slide background-size *ngFor="let item of Offer" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + item.PICPATH + ')'}">

    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS you can do

```
.bg{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

and in your HTML

```
<ion-slides pager="true">
    <ion-slide>
     <div class="bg" *ngFor="let item of Offer" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + item.PICPATH + ')'}></div>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

This will ensure that the images are being properly fit into the `ion-slide`

Comment: this did not work it work when the app direcation is ltr and my app direcation is rtl but this did work direction: ltr !important; sorry the truble I forget that I  direction of the app